# Are Wavenet voices still supported through the Node JS Google Text-to-speech client?

Tags: node.js, google-text-to-speech

Are Wavenet voices still supported through the Node JS Google Text-to-speech client? It used to work before on v.1.3.0 of the NodeJs client and now it is not. I am getting the following error now when I try to generate speech using a Wavenet voice:
`Request contains an invalid argument`

Regular voices work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I work on Google Cloud Text-to-Speech.

Yes, WaveNet is supposed to work. Can you try to reproduce your synthesis request using a curl command and copy/paste your command payload here?

Comment: It Looks like it started working again. I just tested it again and it now works fine. It looks was just a temporary issue.